# equivalent of sklearn's StratifiedGroupKFold for PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, scikit-learn, cross-validation, training-data, train-test-split

I have a dataframe for single-label binary classification with some class imbalance and I want to make a train-test split. Some observations are members of groups in the data that should only appear in either the test split or train split but not both.

Outside of `PySpark`, I could use `StratifiedGroupKFold` from `sklearn`. What is the easiest way to achieve the same effect with `PySpark`?

I looked at the `sampleBy` method from `PySpark`, but I'm not sure how to use it while keeping the groups separate.

Documentation links:

- [StratifiedGroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html)
- [sampleBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.sampleBy.html)